# SizeToContent after Resizing

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to be able to change the breadth of the program, which I can also do. The problem is that the program can be expanded and collapsed. However, if I change the width of the program, the `SizeToContent` no longer works. The height that should change automatically does not change any more.

```
<mah:MetroWindow  x:Class="PSX_Runner.MainWindow"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
              xmlns:g="clr-namespace:PSX_Runner.ViewModels"
              mc:Ignorable="d"
              Title="PSX Runner"
              Icon="/Resources/alien_4as_icon.ico"
              ResizeMode="CanResize"
              SizeToContent="Height"
              Height="{Binding GUI.Height, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
              Width="{Binding GUI.Width, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
              Left="{Binding GUI.Left, Mode=TwoWay}"
              Top="{Binding GUI.Top, Mode=TwoWay}"
              WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
              Topmost="{Binding GUI.TopMost}"
              ResizeBorderThickness="8, 0">
```

[Unfolded state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lzdf.png)

[Collapsed state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcKcI.png)

[Unfolded state after changing width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O7OQ.png)

That is also the order in which everything was carried out. And if I hadn't changed the width, the program would have unfolded again as in the first picture.
Any approaches to make `SizeToContent` sensitive to the `Height` again?

Comment: Could you check if SizeToContent is changing itself to Manual after collapsing? From the docs: `SizeToContent is automatically set to Manual if a user resizes the window by using the resize grip or dragging the border.`, and while you aren't using the resize grip/border, I want to confirm that's not happening somehow

Comment: Thanks @Vultuxe for your fast answer.
I've tested it now and it changes to Manuel. But how do I counteract this?

Comment: When I expand / collapse, I now always change ´SizeToContent´ to the ´height´, that's how it works. Thanks for your tip @Vultuxe.